# How to set SVG icon to map marker on HERE map using Here Android SDK

Tags: java, android, here-api

MapMarker `setIcon` accept Image as parameter. I couldn't find any overload that accept svg string Or raw file to make icon. Is there any way to use raw SVG file as icon with Here Map marker.

PS: I am using HERE map Android SDK.

Answer (score 0):

Please see the following links to create an image from [path](https://developer.here.com/mobile-sdks/documentation/android-premium/topics_api_nlp_hybrid_plus/com-here-android-mpa-common-image.html#topic-apiref__setimageasset-string) and by [data](https://developer.here.com/mobile-sdks/documentation/android-premium/topics_api_nlp_hybrid_plus/com-here-android-mpa-common-image.html#topic-apiref__setimagedata-byte-array). Note we do not fully support SVG. I would recommend you rasterize one first and pass it in as an Android Bitmap.

Comment: How can i change SVG text dynamically ? e.g If i want to show marker in form of circle with it identification number within circle.

Comment: We do not offer or expose any SVG rasterization parameters. I would suggest you use Android's framework to rasterize the SVG and then pass it to the HERE SDK.

Comment: Doesn't work. Both methods setImageAsset() and setImageData() don't support SVG!

Comment: @goflo as per my comment  SVG is not fully supported, so your assumptions do not work.

Comment: @DavidLeong but I'm wondering for what the setSvgIconScaling() method of the MapMarker class can be used? If we can't use SVG images this method seems to be useless. https://developer.here.com/documentation/android-premium/topics_api_nlp_hybrid_plus/com-here-android-mpa-mapping-mapmarker.html#topic-apiref__setsvgiconscaling-float

Comment: Because internally there is only a basic rasterizer. I believe this method was exposed by mistake and should not be available publically.